# Share link on google plus along with Title, Image and Description

Tags: php

I want to share a link on Google plus posts with parameters Title, Image and Description.
But even this simple code doesn't work for me.

**Issue is that**:
Image is not shown,
Title is not shown,
Description is not shown.

For Test Purpose here is the link of of site for this code.
http://getreferralace.com/gonawazgo.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Basic page</title>
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.getreferralace.com/campagins_view?id=21" />
<meta property="og:title" content="This is Referral Ace" />
<meta property="og:description" content="This is decription for Referral Ace" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.getreferralace.com/campagins_view?id=21" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.getreferralace.com/campaign_images/Tulips.jpg" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://www.getreferralace.com/campagins_view?id=21" target="_blank" class="gplus-counter" id="gplus_share">Share</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i don't see an image tag

Comment: here it is.<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.getreferralace.com/campaign_images/Tulips.jpg" />

Comment: Hey donald123, Would it work?

Comment: Now i also added Image tag but still it not worked.

Comment: http://puu.sh/dlU7y.jpg for me theres no problem.. Maybe the wrong url?

Comment: Sure no problem there but where is the description???

Comment: I want to say my third parameter "Description" is not shown.

Answer (score 0):

Your href tag is not sharing the correct link to google plus:

The link your sharing is: http://www.getreferralace.com/campagins_view?id=21 which results in a 404 error page.

So you can use the below link:

```
<a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://www.getreferralace.com/gonawazgo.php" target="_blank" class="gplus-counter" id="gplus_share">Share</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for Answer and it almost worked. But without description.

Comment: @MaqsoodAhmad that's good. Just a question why didn't you just use something like addthis?

Comment: I didn't understand. Can you explain?

Comment: Snippet is working now but description is not shown.

Answer (score 0):

**Discription is not shown.**
Everthing else is working fine.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Basic page</title>
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://www.getreferralace.com/gonawazgo.php" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="This is Referral Ace" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="This is decription for Referral Ace" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.getreferralace.com/gonawazgo.php" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.getreferralace.com/campaign_images/Tulips.jpg" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js">
    </script>
    </head>
    <body class="body_style" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
    <div class="abc" style="display: none;">
     <h1 itemprop="name">Title Pizza</h1>
      <img itemprop="image" src="http://www.getreferralace.com/campaign_images/Tulips.jpg" />
      <p itemprop="description">This is decription for Referral Ace</p>
    </div>
    <a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://www.getreferralace.com/gonawazgo.php" target="_blank" class="gplus-counter" id="gplus_share">Share</a>
    </body>
    </html>
    </html>
```